# Hide element, but show CSS generated content

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a way of hiding an element's contents, but keep its `:before` content visible?
Say I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<span class="addbefore hidetext">You are here</span>
```

CSS:

```
.addbefore:before {
    content: "Show this";
}
.hidetext {
    // What do I do here to hide the content without hiding the :before content?
}
```

I've tried:

- using `display: none` and setting `display: inline` on `:before`, but both are still hidden
- using `width: 0; overflow: hidden`;, but then additional space seems to be added (?)
- using color: transparent;, but then, of course, the content of the span still takes up space
- using `text-indent: -....px`, but

  1. this is frowned upon by search engines and
  2. it seems not to work for span elements (?)

Any other ideas as to how I might do this?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

## Clean Solution

You could use `visibility: hidden`, but with this solution, the hidden content will still *take up space*. If this doesn't matter to you, this is how you would do it:

```
span {
    visibility: hidden;
}

span:before {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

---

## Hackish Alternative Solution

Another solution would be to set the `font-size` of the span <del>to zero</del>* to a really small value. Advantage of this method: The hidden content won't take up any space. Drawback: You won't be able to use relative units like em or % for the font-size of the `:before` content.

```
span:before {
    content: "Lorem ";
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem; /* Maintain relative font-size in browsers that support it */
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #000;
}

span {
    font-size: 1px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    color: transparent;
}
```

[Example on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/8jJ6W/)

**Update (May 4, 2015):** With CSS3, you can now use the `rem` (Root EM) unit to maintain relative font-sizes in the `:before` element. [(Browser support.)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=rem)

---

*A previous version of this post suggested setting the font size to zero. However, this does not work as desired in some browsers, because CSS does not define what behavior is expected [when the font-size is set to zero](http://webdesign.about.com/od/fonts/qt/tipfont0.htm). For cross-browser compatibility, use a small font size like mentioned above.

Comment: Hmm.. That last one is actually pretty good.. I'm using this to add icons with an icon font before text, so setting the font size in pixels might be a good idea anyway.. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it seems as though setting font-size: 0 isn't possible..? In Chrome at least, the jsfiddle you attached still shows "Ipsum", just in very small letters..

Comment: Hmm, in my Firefox it does work. You could try setting a really, really low value, like `0.000000000001em`, or you could try setting `0em`.

Comment: I'd love to give a thumbs up, but apparently I don't have enough reputation.. =) Also, 0em and 0.000001em don't work either...

Comment: @Wolfy87 Have you read anything I wrote in the first post? Or the part about :before being a child of the targeted element from Sotiris?

Comment: This is strange... By the way, I wouldn't have asked you for a thumbs up, if I knew that it doesn't work. :) I've updated the second solution, i hope this will work.

Comment: The `visibility`-approach does not work in IE unfortunately. The `letter-spacing`-approach works, but the correct value for `letter-spacing` is `normal`, not `auto`.

Comment: One major drawback: You cannot use this if you do not know the original font-size, e.g. because all your sizes are relative.

Comment: `font-size: 0.01em` for the span and `font-size: 100em` for the pseudo element should also do the right thing without having to reset to the root `rem` value

Comment: The `visibility` approach breaks tab focus for form elements.

Answer (score 10):

**For better browser support:**

Wrap the text that should be hidden within an additional `span` element, and apply classes to that span to hide the text you wish to be hidden.

HTML:

```
<span class="addbefore">
  <span class="visuallyhidden">This text will not show.</span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.addbefore:before {
  content: "Show this";
}

.visuallyhidden {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}
```

The `.visuallyhidden` class used above is from the current version of [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate): https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/css/main.css

The advantages of this solution:

- Semantic HTML
- Complete browser support
- No problems with tiny text like other small `font-size` solutions.
- The hidden content won't take up space

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/tinystride/A9SSb/

Comment: Bootstrap uses the class `sr-only` for items that are visually hidden, but still important for screen readers.

Answer (score 3):

I took a similar approach as suggested here with `visibility`, but that still has a content box.

My solution is to simply use `font-size` to hide the target text.

```
span {
    font-size: 0;
}

span:before {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @anroesti's excellent hack, here's a solution if you need to apply in unknown contexts in terms of font size and color, i.e. you are not sure if resetting to `color:black;font-size:1rem;` will not mess things up:

```
<span abbrev-content="Intl.">International</span>

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {  /* very narrow viewports */
    span[abbrev-content] { font-size: 0.001em; visibility: hidden; }
    span[abbrev-content]::before { 
        content: attr(abbrev-content); 
        font-size: 1000em; 
        visibility: visible; 
    }
}
```

If your span content is a paragraph and not just a word, you may also need the negative letter-spacing.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think it's possible with pure css and html. Looking at this example http://jsbin.com/efeco4 you will see that what is inside `content` property of css, is wrapped by the element. So any manipulation of the element will affect the css `content` also.

So an alternative thought could be to use jquery, to empty the html content inside tag `div` with class `hidetext` without affect the `content` of css. A sample code could be this:

```
$('.hidetext').empty();
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/efeco4/2

Comment: I personally would recommend using CSS over JavaScript, as some users may have that **deactivated**.

Comment: @andre_roesti  Well for the 1% of users that have deactivate javascript, I think it's time to take a step further

Comment: I think depending on the target group more than just 1% have deactivated JavaScript, and there are [good Reasons](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/26179/why-do-people-disable-javascript) for doing that.