# Hide some text through CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a website through WordPress and for some reason, I can edit the `CSS` but not the `HTML`, and I want to hide some text but not all off of it. The code is:

```css
.entry-header .entry-title::after {
  content: "Create Theme" !important;
}
```

```html
<header class="entry-header ">
  <h1 class="entry-title ">
            "Create Course"
            ::after
        </h1>
</header>
```

Which displays: `Create CourseCreate Theme`. And I want it to display: `Create Theme`. Is this possible through `CSS`?

Comment: I would find the root of your problem, first - rather than finding hacks to solve your issue. *WHY* can't you edit the HTML? Permissions? No HTML to edit for the page in question? I had a bad experience with a WP site before, where there was no HTML in the homepage - someone had gone and set it all in a template! This was hidden somewhere under the hood of the site's template settings. If possible, try and address the deeper problem you're experiencing :)

Answer (score 3):

This might be a little ugly hack but considering your situation if you can't modify the HTML you could play with `text-indent` to hide the original text and then overwrite the `text-indent` of the parent by setting `display: block;` to the after pseudo element like this:

```css
.entry-header .entry-title {
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

.entry-header .entry-title::after {
  text-indent: 0px !important;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  content: "Create Theme";
}
```

```html
<header class="entry-header ">
  <h1 class="entry-title ">Create Course</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: @JonSmith - don't forge to mark as "accepted" when possible, if this answer solved your problem :)

Answer (score 2):

If you think the `visibility` is fine, try [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8c6vh8k3/1/):

```
.entry-header .entry-title {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.entry-header .entry-title::after {
    content: "Create Theme" !important;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

The problem is that the text `entry-title` will still occupy the space.

Reference: [Hide element, but show CSS generated content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912765/hide-element-but-show-css-generated-content)