# Can I specify custom syntax highlighting in an atom language package?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm writing a language grammar, and as an example, I'd like to display `->` as `➡`, without changing the actual text. 
Is this possible to do in a language package? How?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's a good idea. How would a user make out the difference between a fake `➡` and a literal `➡`? Unicode is everywhere these days, don't keep people from using it.

Apart from these concerns, I think the best way would be to use (or create) a font that uses [ligatures](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Typographic_ligature). [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) seems to have several ligatures for coding.

Another possibility *could* be assigning a special class for `->` (e.g. `.arrow`), then hide it and override its `content`.

**Example:**

```
atom-text-editor::shadow {
    span.arrow.yourgrammar {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    span.arrow.yourgrammar:before {
        content: "\21DB";
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

There are still some disadvantages to consider. First, there will be visible space ([this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912765/hide-element-but-show-css-generated-content) might help). More importantly, copy & paste will act in undesirable ways.

As I said before, I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: To explain why I want this, fstar-mode for emacs does this- it also does things like displaying 'int' as ℤ and 'nat' as ℕ. I'm trying to port it to Atom.

Comment: Maybe ask around on the [Atom forum](https://discuss.atom.io/), people usually get good responses there

Comment: Back to ligatures: Maybe you can request this feature for [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode), it already has a couple of ligatures for programming