# how to make pseudo element visible and clickable using css on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, pseudo-element

I have a button followed by a pseudo element. The button displays 'next' and the pseudo element displays '>'. This is used for pagination.

I have hidden the button but made the pseudo element visible by using css properties

```
button{
    visibility: hidden;
}
button::pseudoElement{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Now the button is hidden and element is visible. It is also clickable. It works in chrome,safari and ie. But it does not click on firefox. What do I change?

EDIT
This hack worked

```
  button{
        color: transparent;
    }
    button::pseudoElement{
        color: black;
    }
```

Any better approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide element, but show CSS generated content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912765/hide-element-but-show-css-generated-content)

Comment: Also please note that questions asking 'why doesn't my code work' require a [mcve]; *pseudo-code is not adequate*.

Comment: Since that code part, using `visibility: hidden/visible;` work and is clickable in Firefox, you need to post a code snippet that reproduce the issue you have.

Answer (score -1):

Pseudo elements aren't actually inserted before or after the element itself. They are inserted as the first/last *child* element. So if you hide the "parent" element, their `::before`/`::after` pseudo elements will be hidden as well.

In your case, I would just do the old `text-indent: -9999px` or `font-size: 0` trick on the parent element and reset the pseudo element (`text-indent: 0`).

With your `color: transparent` solution, the element will retain its size. With the `text-indent` trick it's just using the space the pseudo element needs.

Comment: As using `visibility: hidden/visible;` works just fine, need for _bad hacks_. Why it does not for OP is another story.

Comment: As OP askes _"how to make pseudo element visible and clickable using css on firefox
"_, it works just fine to click on the pseudo using Firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/6vdkn8bg/1/

Comment: I don't get it. They also said _visible_. And `visibility: hidden` makes it _invisible_. But maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: If you check OP's first CSS sample you'll see what they had, and what they said does not work...which it does.